# Проблема с ботом, дублирует сообщения

Tags: php, mysql, вконтакте, бот

Добрый день столкнулся с такой проблемой что бот вк дублирует мои сообщения.

````
$user_id = $data->object->from_id; //получение id пользователя
$id = ($user_id == $data->object->peer_id) ? $user_id : $data->object->peer_id; //id пользователя или беседы
$message = explode(" ", $data->object->text);
$cmd = explode(" ",mb_strtolower($data->object->text));





if ($data->type == 'message_new') {

    if (in_array($cmd[0], $checker)){

        if ($message[1] == ''){
        } else {
     
            $result = $db->query("SELECT * from states_core_members WHERE name = '?s' AND status = 0", $message[1]);
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


                $cont .= "--> \nНик: $row[name] \nУровень Администратора: $row[admin]\n Активонсть: $row[last]";

            }

            if ($cont){
                $vk->sendMessage($id, 'Результаты:'.$cont);
            } 

        }

        }



}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XaC4.jpg
````

Comment: `ok` возвращаете ? Если да, то еще может дублироваться из за  того, что на какой то старый запрос не был получен ответ. callback это любит. Выход - юзать лонгпул, либо отвечать на все запросы.

Comment: Да возвращаю ..

Comment: Киньте через pastebin полный код проблемного скрипта. Если в нем нет фич. Это  будет лучше, чем смотреть на обрезок кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще есть несколько причин из-за чего это может происходить:

1. Хостинг вводит ваш проект в режим сна, а, когда **вконтакте** отправляет запрос, проект начинает просыпаться и отправлять ответ, но не успевает и **вконтакте** приходится отправлять второй запрос. Такое явление наблюдается на популярном хостинге **Heroku**. Понять, что у вас именно это проблема можно так: обратитесь к боту два раза (допустим написав какую-то команду или слово в сообщения), если на первое обращение(команду) он ответит дублированием, а на второе нет, то у вас именно это проблема. Решением может служить только смена хостинга
2. Если сообщения дублируются много раз и постоянно, то это именно этот случай. Проблема тут заключается не в вас, а в **вконтакте**, это баг, который они не особо хотят фиксить. Чтобы устранить данный недуг нужно отправлять запросы методом **POST**, а не **GET**, хотя в документации про это ни слово.

Для начала нам понадобится массив с данными для запроса

```
$request_params = array(
                    'message' => "", //сообщение
                    'access_token' => TOKEN_VK_BOT, //токен для отправки от имени сообщества
                    'peer_id' => $data->object->message->from_id, //айди пользователя
                    'random_id' => 0, //0 - не рассылка
                    'read_state' => 1, //Хз зачем но надо
                    'user_ids' => 0, // Отправляете только 1 пользователю
                    'v' => VERSION_API_VK, //Версия API Vk
                    'payload' => 1000, //Хз зачем но надо
                    'attachment' => '' //Вложение
                );
```

Изменить какой-то параметр, например, чтобы указать сообщение, можно так:

```
$request_params['message'] = "hello world!";
```

Дальше для отправки нам понадобится эта функция

```
function sendPOST($request_params){
        $myCurl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($myCurl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($request_params),
        ));
        curl_exec($myCurl);
        curl_close($myCurl);
    }
```

И наконец отправляем

```
sendPOST($request_params);
                echo "ok";
```

И чтобы всё это заработало необходимо добавить **curl** зависимость в ваш composer.json

```
{
  "require" : {
    ...
    "ext-curl": "*"
  },
  
}
```

Вообще есть ещё одно решение проблемы, но это говно код и я вообще не понимаю почему это работает. Нужно вывести **ok** разными способами одновременно, например **return**, **echo**, **die** и т.д., например вот

```
echo 'ok';
return 'ok';
die 'ok';
```

Comment: @CryEngine V - FlowGraph, я открою тебе секрет, но код на языке php. А это язык сайтов. Вконтакте делает запрос на сайт. Мне чо бота размещать как исполняемый файл на своем компе и открывать порты? Любое видео открой по написанию бота в вк на php, в каждом говорят, что нужен хостинг для загрузки бота. 
А в чем проблема Heroku? Его миллионы людей используют под Web проекты ведь для этого он и был сделан.
Про то что это не зависит от POST или GET затирай техподдержке, которая сама говорит обратное
Каждый метод в API требует версии, по крайней мере на API от начала лета

Comment: Спасибо помог..

Answer (score 0):

У вк есть параметр сообщений random_id. Как раз против такой шляпы сделан. Он не отправит второе сообщение, если первое уже отправилось. Не нужно менять хост/ещё что-то, можно просто использовать random_id.